# Reverse of Queue

Tags: java, collections, queue

I want to reverse a queue by using Java collection framework. But I am not able to understand how can I do it?

How can I reverse the Queue in java using java collection framework?

Answer (score 0):

If you use a  `LinkedList` wich implements java `Queue` this is very simple:

```
    LinkedList<String> queue = new LinkedList<>();
    Collections.reverse(queue);
```

Otherwise, you have to use a stack. Pool every element of the queue in the stack and take them out and add back in the queue.

```
public static <T> void reverse(Queue<T> queue) {
    Deque<T> stack = new LinkedList<>();

    while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
        stack.push(queue.poll());
    }

    while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
        queue.add(stack.pop());
    }
}
```